# Input 1D array with float datatype in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pytorch, tensor, torchscript

I would like to input row = [0.160625, 0.967468297, 3.520480583, 0.862454481, -0.341933766] as entry which is float type and pass it to forward module. I used python trying to translate to C++,
I got syntax error. Support needed. Thanks!

```
    // run not okay
    // Create a vector of inputs.
    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
    row = [0.190625, 0.957468297, 4.520480583, 0.962454481, -0.241933766]
    inputs.push_back(torch::tensor(row));

    // Execute the model and turn its output into a tensor.
    at::Tensor output = module.forward(inputs).toTensor();
    std::cout << output.slice(/*dim=*/1, /*start=*/0, /*end=*/4) << '\n';
```

I would like to use row as instance and get the output.
When I use dummy values such as torch::one({1, 5}), the app run ok.
However, when I passed the real value as row - the float array, the app is aborted.

```
    // run ok for this case 
    // Create a vector of inputs.
    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
    inputs.push_back(torch::ones({ 1, 5}));

    // Execute the model and turn its output into a tensor.
    at::Tensor output = module.forward(inputs).toTensor();
    std::cout << output.slice(/*dim=*/1, /*start=*/0, /*end=*/4) << '\n';
```

Comment: Tried to replace `[]` with `{}`?

Comment: You may have to show us what a `row` is.

Comment: row here is a float array: row = [0.190625, 0.957468297, 4.520480583, 0.962454481, -0.241933766]

Comment: I got an error saying row is undeclared identifier after I changed row from [ ] with { }

Comment: @Adelyn not in c++ as c++ does not support that syntax. Is it `std::vector<float> row;`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try replacing `[]` with `{}` as mentioned before?

```cpp
float row[] = { 0.190625, 0.957468297, 4.520480583, 0.962454481, -0.241933766 };
```

Comment: Thank you. I did. However,  when I run the app, it is aborted due to data type error. If I use dummy value such as  "inputs.push_back(torch::ones({ 1, 5}))"; my app run ok. My instance is 1D array with 5 float numbers. I name it row.  I want to pass row as input to get output.

Comment: put `f` at the end of the number, like `0.190625f`